# Prove that an intersection-free family in $[n]^{(r)}$ has size at most $1+\binom{r}{\lfloor \frac{r}{2}\rfloor}$ (Sperner's lemma)

Tags: combinatorics

A set system $\mathcal{A} ⊂ [n]^{(r)}$ is called intersection-free if no distinct $A, B, C ∈ A $ satisfy $A ∩ B ⊂ C$. Prove that an intersection-free family in $[n]^{(r)}$ has size at most $1+\binom{r}{\lfloor \frac{r}{2}\rfloor}$.

I kinda get how to do it (fixing a set $B_0 ∈ \mathcal{A}$, and observe that $\{A∩B_0 : A ∈ \mathcal{A}, A\neq B_0\}$ is an antichain over $B_0$ and use Sperner's lemma) , but what I'm wondering is, isn't the family already an antichain, since all the sets have the same size and so cannot be contained in each other?

Comment: Would you mind to explain more? For instance what does the exponent in parentheses mean? As you are using intersections, one would think one has subsets of some set (universe), in which case $\mathcal A$ should be part of some power-set, maybe $\mathcal P([n])$, but then what is $r$? And why does the formula not involve $n$? And why the term $1$?

Comment: Your idea about 'how to do it' written in the parenthesis works. Answering your question: Yes, the family (the set of all $r$-subsets of $[n]$) is an antichain. But what you are looking for is the size of the largest 'intersection-free' family.